# How to add a webhook in Strapi?

Tags: node.js, webhooks, strapi

I'm aware the feature is pending according to [strapi.io/vote](https://strapi.io/vote) under **Plugins - Webhooks**.

I'd like some guidance into how to setup it up at framework level in strapi from someone who has the experience.

Comment: `strapi generate:api webhooks` and you'd only use the controller. You could even do; `strapi:generate:api common` and add a `webhooks.js` controller. Any other generic things could be added to this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the feature is available in the latest version.
Kindly refer :
[webhooks](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#webhooks)